# In Jeffrey Carver's the "Reefs of Time" dedication page, who is "Chuck"?

Tags: the-chaos-chronicles

In Jeffrey Carver's the "Reefs of Time" dedication page, who is "Chuck"? Does anyone know?  Thanks

> This is for Chuck. You waited so long, and then were snatched away too soon. And for all you readers and fans who also waited a very long time. Thank you for your loyalty and patience.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Chuck" was Jeffrey's older brother, Charles S. Carver. He died of cancer in 2019 just after *The Reefs of Time* was published. There is a heart-felt obituary for him on Jeffrey's [blog](https://www.starrigger.net/2019/06/23/charles-s-carver-1947-2019/).